# Trying to hyperlink a heading for a CV section on Overleaf

Tags: hyperref, resume

I am working on Overleaf making a resume, and I have hyperlinked my CV heading as follows:

```
\cvsection {\href{https://simply-delicious-food.com/homemade-chicken-nuggets/{Research Exposure}}
```

The hyperlink shows up successfully, but when clicking on it I get the following error:
404 the requested URL was not found on this server. This problem only occurs for headers; all my other links work perfectly fine.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\href` has two required arguments, did you mean to write `\href{https://simply-delicious-food.com/homemade-chicken-nuggets/}{Research Exposure}`?

Comment: as you have typed it, your browser is looking for `https://.../{Research Exposure}` which doesn't exist on your web page.

Comment: Yep sorry I left out the } closing off the url in my post but it remains the same. I think I discovered the issue. So once I download the pdf the link for some reason shows up in all caps which is why it won't route properly to the website. However, I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it. I think it might have to do with the fact that \cvsection is a heading and all of it is in caps.